# Interpolation raster to a given point in R but controlling the interpolation area of influence

Tags: r, interpolation

Given the SpatRaster r below, how can I interpolate to the point p(x,y) using all the non-NA points located within a certain distance from p? The interpolation method can be either bilinear or average or maximum.  But I need to be able to control the interpolation area-of-influence size, either by specifying a radius or a number of grid cells around p.

```
m <- matrix(1:100, nrow=10, ncol=10)
r <- rast(m)
p <- data.frame(x=20,y=30)
```

I need something like this

```
val <- interpolation (m,p,radius=5)
```

Comment: Sounds like a combination of https://rspatial.github.io/terra/reference/focal.html and https://rspatial.org/spatial/8-rastermanip.html#accessing-cell-values.